# ScrollView slow scroll and items disappearing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-scrollview

I'm trying to add a ScrollView to hold a header and a RecyclerView.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:cropToPadding="false" />


    </RelativeLayout>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

But I had 2 problems trying this:

- The relative layout id/profile is disappearing. When I open the activity it appears for 1 sec and disappears.
- The RecyclerView scroll is too slow.

any ideas?

Comment: make Relative layout as parent. and inside it make NestedScrollview. now move other layout and recyclerview in it

Comment: Why `RecyclerView` under `ScrollView` ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I want to scroll the header (id/profile) and the recyclerview together. if I do not add scrollview I cannot scroll the header.

Answer (score 5):

By default, `RecyclerView` has its own scroll, which conflicts with your `ScrollView`. To fix it,  change the the `ScrollView` to `NestedScrollView`.

Comment: @GabrielaDias It's a perfect answer .

Comment: @LuizFernandoSalvaterra Its our Duty :) . Move ahead

Comment: I add: `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` but all still the same, the header is disappearing and the scroll is still slow ;/

Answer (score 2):

Put recyclerView in NestedScrollView in XML

```
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                 android:id="@+id/recycler_pracstice_loaction"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scrollbars="none" />
            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And in Activity :

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Surely, You will  get what you want. This will solve your Recyclerview Scrolling Problem

Add below code in your activity it will solve your Automatically Scroll Problem.

```
recyclerView.setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. and where can I add my header?

Comment: wait few minutes i giving you answer that you are facing automatically scrolls.

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if my answer is helpful for you, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
   recylerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

please set this property of recylerview.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this project. Its not a Library. Its a Demo code...I Think what you are searching for

check out here https://github.com/kmshack/Android-ParallaxHeaderViewPager

Answer (score 0):

change your scrollview to NestedScrollView.

> The relative layout id/profile is disappearing. when I open the
>   activity it appears for 1 sec and disappear.

Your recyclerview is loading itens hover the relativeLayout, so, add this in your recyclerview:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/profile"
```

> The recyclerview scroll is too slow.

Just add the code below in your activity:

```
recylerview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```